# Custom permissions on attachments based on condition

Tags: apex, sharing, permissions, apex-managed-sharing

My requirement is, i want to set access permission on account attachments when check box custom field is not checked, means if check box is set true then user has permission to access the attachments, if not user has no permissions to access the attachments.

I tried to hide related list of attachments using javascript using home page components; it worked but what if someone directly paste the url of attachment into address bar.

Any directions/suggestions will greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Best way I can think of is to take it off the page layout and then display the related list in a visualforce page and control the visibility from that.